# How to get docker applications to send logs to openshift's built in log aggregator?

Tags: docker, openshift, fluentd

I am setting up an Openshift cluster and am trying to aggregate the logs using the built in EFK stack that Openshift builds when I start the cluster with:

```
oc cluster up --logging=true
```

However, as I add other projects and docker images to nodes, I am not quite sure how to funnel the application logs to the created logging project. How do I get the logs to report to the created EFK cluster?

Comment: What do you mean by ``add other projects and docker images to nodes``? Are you adding stuff to nodes outside of OpenShift? If you deploy applications using OpenShift, so long as they log to stdout/stderr that will be captured.

Comment: I have a logging project that is created by openshift when the cluster is created, and then add a second project in openshift and deploy docker containers to it. It seems that the image is putting messages out to the console but I don't see it it register in the Kibana output in the first project. Does that help?